# Do these sentences have the same meaning with past perfect?

Tags: meaning, grammar, usage, past-perfect

"I saw a movie before I came here that I had never seen." vs " I had never seen such a movie before I came here". are these have same meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Your sentences are grammatically correct, but they don't mean the same thing.

> I saw a movie before I came here that I had never seen.

This means you saw a movie *before* you came here.  If you came to place B from place A, you saw the movie in A.  Moreover, it was a movie you had never seen.  (You may have seen movies before, and even movies similar to this one, but not this specific one.)

> I had never seen such a movie before I came here.

This means you saw the movie *after* you came here.  If you came from place B to place A, you saw the movie in B.  Not only had you never seen this movie, but you had never seen any movie quite like it.  (The sentence does *not* say that you had never seen a movie before coming here.)

Answer (score -1):

they don't have the same meaning and those sentences are wrong in english.it should be:
**i had been watching a movie before i came here,which i hadn't seen before until then.

i had never seen a movie like that until when just before coming here.** the "i had never seen such a movie..." is mean that you hadn't seen any movie in your life.

Comment: Not *any* movie - just the sort indicated by *such*.